# How to wait until all submitted tasks in ExecutorService are completed without shutdown?

Tags: java, executorservice, executors

Imagine we traverse a collection and submit tasks to be run in background

```
class Processor {
    public void process(Iterable<Item> items, ExecutorService executorService) {
       for (Item item : items) {               
           doStandardProcess(item);               
           if (needSpecialProcess(item)) {
               executorService.submit(createSpecialTaskFor(item));
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Program flow looks like:

1. receive items from somewhere
2. create Processor and process them
3. send the result to somewhere

Result depends on the background processing, so p.3 should wait until all tasks will be completed. I know it can be achieved by the combination of `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()`, but I do not want to shutdown the service. Also there is a possibility to call `invokeAll(List tasks)`, but as you see, tasks are created one by one during traverse.

How can I achieve waiting for completion with given restrictions?

P.S. If it was not clear, another restriction is to run background tasks in parallel with items traversal, because background tasks takes x100 more time than basic processing operation.

Comment: Use Scala futures: `val proc = items.map{ item => Future{ doStandardProcess(item); if (needSpecialProcess(item)) doSpecialTask(item)}}; val result =  Future.sequence(proc)`  you will need functional versions of those side-effecting methods, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the futures:

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<> ();
//in the for loop
futures.add(executorService.submit(createTaskFor(item)));

//after for loop + add exception handling
for (Future f : futures) f.get();
//at this point all tasks have finished
```

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I'm not sure I understand what you need exactly but an [ExecutoriCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Callable<Foo>> toProcess = new ArrayList<>();
for (Item item : items) {
    if (needProcess(item)) {
        toProcess.add(createTaskFor(item));
    }
}
executorService.invokeAll(toProcess);
```

Comment: will not work, traversing items and executing tasks are not parallel in this example

Comment: It will work. You didn't say that the traversal has to be done in parallel to the execution. If `needProcess()` is so expensive that it needs to be done in parallel, then it should be part of the task itself. Otherwise, the calls to `needProcess()` are not done in parallel anyway, but sequentially, in the main thread. And if it's fast enough to be done sequentially, it's also probably fast enough to be done before submitting the tasks.

Comment: ok, i'll mention it in a question additionally. needProcess is not expensive, I don't understand why you mentioned it, the only goal was to finish the traversal and tasks executing at the same time.

Comment: If it's not expensive, then there is no problem in iterating on all the items to extract those which must be processed before submitting the tasks. It will make no significant performance difference.

Comment: There is a problem, there are 100.000 items and they are traversed and processed somehow. For some of them (~1000) I need to perform additional time consuming actions (http calls). If I run them after the loop, I'll spend much more time than if I run them in parallel.

Comment: I see where is the misunderstanding, you thought that I have just a one loop which is fast.

Comment: Not *much more time*. Iterating over 100,000 elements and keeping some of them in a list executes in less than a millisecond. Making a single HTTP request needs much more than that (probably 500 milliseconds). So the overhead is insignificant.